# Running Insert query in SSIS Package

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis

I'm new to SSIS packages. I have to run a INSERT query which will be result on an SELECT query.
1) I will run the select query using ODBC source and it will return 6 columns and one of them will be the INSERT query.
I tried putting the query in Flat file destination(.sql extension) it comes out to be fine but cannot fetch it I don't know why might be because of it is dynamic insert query.

Can anyone help me how can I do that?

Comment: Show us the code you used to attempt to fetch the insert query from the flat file.   We can't help debug what we can't see.

Comment: I don't have any code written for that, I was wondering if it will be possible without writing that query to a file. Like from ODBC source i would just fetch the last column and run the INSERT query.

Comment: You could store it in a variable.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do that? Currently I'm running query in ODBC source and under column tab I've selected the query column.

Answer (score 0):

From your SELECT query, store the value of the column containing the INSERT query in a package variable.   Then for your INSERT query, choose the "query from variable" option and use the variable as the source.

[This tutorial](http://www.sqlis.com/post/The-Execute-SQL-Task.aspx) shows how to store the result of a select query in a variable.